# springboot override controller methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, customization

I have to ask because none of the answers I found can help me to solve my problem.

I have controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
DefaultController
```

I want to override its methods because one specific customer has specific logics, with controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path")
CustomController
```

that can have exactly same methods signatures or overriding methods with RequestBody extending the original requests.

1. I tried to define an interface for controllers where I put the annotations
2. I used @Primary and @Profile on CustomController to force Spring to load it rather than the default version

Solutions don't work because Spring detects a double mapping for methods, the famous "Ambiguous mapping".

Has anybody any idea how i could solve the situation?

I want literally plug custom implementations of controllers, only where I need, overriding only methods I need, without altering request path.
Customizing Services is not enough, because sometimes I have to pass RequestBody with additional fields

We are using springboot 2.4.7, spring 5.3.8

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are able to start the app by using a profile for each customer, you can do it. But do you need both customers at the same time, your only way to manage this behaviour is to implement different services. And I dont see any problem to solve it in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my problem.
I did this, if anybody interested

1. assigned a specific profile to overriding controller via @Profile("what you want")
2. added custom header to controller request mapping, via @RequestMapping attribute "headers"
3. only for post and put methods, I had to set a value again for attribute "headers", both on original and custom controller

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `@Profile` for this, `@Profile` is good for things like customizing tests or builds. You just need to create a separate controller and name the paths accordingly, there is really no good reason to try to override controller methods. Spring won't even allow you to do it because of the duplicate paths. Even if it was somehow possible, imagine the troubleshooting nightmare it would create, how would anybody apart from you know "which" controller is actually deployed in the production system.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.
Whe you write "create a separate controller and name the paths accordingly" you mean that CustomController should be mapped under @Path("/path/custom") or similar?
But in this way, front-end should be aware of the existence of different paths. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The point is endpoints should always be unique. Even if they do similar things behind the scenes, you can reuse code in the backend layer. The controller should be the dumbest, simplest layer in the application.

Comment: the problem is not where to put the logic, but how to allow overriding methods with extended beans or the same signature

Comment: You shouldn't try to override controller methods. Use the service layer to reuse any duplicate business logic

Answer (score -1):

If content-type is not your concern, you can try to change the consumer/producer

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/path", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
CustomController
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I would prefer to take advantage of native objects deserialization